# Read only version of node form for anonymous users?

Tags: 8, nodes, users, forms

Use case: a site that accepts applications for courses. Users need to register first before they can create an application (for security, spam etc.) - however the registration process might put them off; can anyone suggest a way to preview the form?

Requests to '/node/add/application' obviously get Access Denied when not logged in, because Anonymous Users don't have the "Application: Create new content" permission.

Comment: You could alter the form and remove the submit button based on whatever condition you want

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone suggest a way to preview the form?

The no code way would be to use screen shots (images).

Alternatively, you could check if the user is logged, it they are not then unset the submit button via a [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.6.x).

> prevent someone from circumventing it by submitting the form manually

Better yet, if user is anonymous, you alter the callback function of the submit button by unsetting the existing one and adding a new custom callback.

Comment: @NoSsweat - thanks - yep, I'd prefer the low maintenance approach (i.e. not regenerating screenshots each time).  What about CSRF tokens - i.e. to prevent someone from circumventing it by submitting the form manually - can I remove those from $form too? (apologies I don't have an IDE available here to check)

Comment: I can see them [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7BoN.png), so yes.

Comment: Or you could leave the submit button and alter the callback. Perhaps the altered callback shows a drupal_set_message saying form was not submitted, please register to be able to submit or something along those lines.